# Getting values from dynamic jsp table

Tags: jsp, dynamic, html-table

I have a table that dynamically generates values from my database. The **list** variable is an arrayList of some Object

```
 <table border="1">
                     <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                     </tr>

                        <%for(int x = 0; x <list.size(); x++) {%>
                        <tr>
                        <td><% out.println(list.get(x).getUsername()); %></td>
                        <td><%out.println(list.get(x).getFirstname() + list.get(x).getMiddleinitial() + list.get(x).getLastname());%></td>
                         <td><% out.println(list.get(x).getStatus()); %></td>
                          <td> 
                              <form action="ViewManager" method="POST">
                                   <input id="button" type="submit" value="View" >
                              </form>
                              <form action="LockManager" method="POST">
                                   <input id="button" type="submit" value="Lock" >
                              </form>
                              <form action="DeleteManager" method="POST">
                                   <input id="button" type="submit" value="Delete" >
                              </form>

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <% }%>


                    </table>
```

What I want is to capture the username of the certain row in where I pressed the button and pass it to a servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it as an additional request parameter with help of a hidden input element.

E.g.

```
<form action="ViewManager" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= list.get(x).getUsername() %>" />
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="View" >
</form>
```

It's available as

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is an oldschool way of writing JSPs. The above approach is also sensitive to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Java/JSP *scriptlet* doesn't have builtin facilities to prevent that. Consider using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` to iterate over the list and `fn:escapeXml()` to escape user-controlled data to prevent XSS attack holes.

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="${fn:escapeXml(user.username)}" />
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Comment: thanks! This would really help so if i were to implement it, how exactly would it look like?

Comment: You're welcome. Just click the links instead of ignoring them as if they are decoration :)